# Sublime Text Copy and Paste

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Recently in Sublime Text 3, I keep running into this bug or even possibly "feature"?

If I copied this line of code:

```
<p>...And it's not too late to claim your front row seat!</p>
```

it will output:

```
p {

}
```

after being pasted.

Anyone else running into this? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: That is odd. I can't reproduce your problem. Can you possibly provide more details so someone can help? For example, where you are copying that text from (maybe the application you are copying text from is the culprit) or the environment of sublime text (what syntax mode is set, plugins, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew, I would copy from a sublime to sublime, it's always in HTML syntax. Current plugins are [Emmet, JShint, JSformat, sublime linter, sidebar] It really is the weirdest thing, and is happening on my home machine as well as work. I am only noticing it on windows machines as a side note (shocker... )

Comment: I've used all those plugins before except Emmet, so that would be my suspect. What happens if you temporarily remove the Emmet package?

Comment: I experience the same issue time from time during recent weeks. Among noted extensions I use _Sublime linter_ and _Emmet_.